# Delete the ith element in constant time

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, complexity-theory

I'm looking for a data structure in Java, that has the following properties:

1. Deletion in `O(1)` time *using the index* inside the structure, while maintaining the relative order of the elements (sorted initially).
2. Addition, only at the end of the structure.
3. No updation is required.
4. Single traversal after all deletions.

**Options that I've tried**:

- **Array:** Can not delete in `O(1)` time, as shifting is required. Plus, if I use a `HashSet` of deleted (or not deleted) elements, then too I would have to go through the deleted elements once, while travelling through the array.
- **Linked List:** Deletion is `O(1)` (if you have a reference to the `Node` to be deleted, and it's a doubly linked list, preferably), and shifting is not necessary. But there is no indexing, so I have to traverse from the start, to determine the `Node` that has to be deleted.
- **`TreeSet`:** A treeset can maintain the order, and deletion is `O(1)` time,but via the element, but not the index inside the structure.

I'm looking for a data structure that can help me in the tasks mentioned above, if possible, in `Java`. If it is not built-in, then I would like to know the implementation of the said data structure.

---

**The need:**
I was trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/fenwick-binary-indexed-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/string-query-22/) question. A string of English characters is given initially, then a number of operations are to be performed on the string. Each operation has a character `c` and a number a`n` alongside, which means that we have to delete `n`th occurrence of the character `c`.

**My solution:**
I would create an array of type `X` (the data structure I am looking for), of length 26 (for each character). I would add each occurrence of a character, say `d`, in the 3rd slot (starting from `0`), in objects that contain the `index` in the String itself. I would do this for all the characters of the String. This would take a total time of `O(n)`, if the length of the string is `n`.

Once this is done, I would start processing the queries. Each query requires us to delete the `n`th occurrence of the character `c` (variable, not the actual English character c), which we can do in `O(1)` time (as required). So, each such deletion would take `O(q)` time, where `q` is the number of queries.

Then we can make a `charArray` that has the length of that of the original string. Then traverse through all the elements remaining in each slot of the array of objects of type `X`, and put them in their respective places. Once this is done, we can traverse this `charArray` again and ignore all the empty places, and construct a string from the elements left.

Comment: you can use a linkedhashmap which keeps the order and its deletion is of O(1) and if you set the index as the key then you can delete by index.

Comment: @epcpu The index is supposed to be calculated from the structure only. Say we have `1 2 3 4 5`, and then if I delete the `4`th element, then we'll have `1 2 3 5`, after which if we delete the `4`th element again, then we should have `1 2 3`.

Comment: @epcpu sorted hash map is `TreeMap` and it based on **binary tree**, and basic operations takes `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik It was just a simple mistake and of course fixed by changing to linkedhashmap.

Comment: @Mooncrater BWT, `Linked List: Deletion is O(1)` is not correct. it is `O(n)` - you have to find element first. In case you aready has iterator in required element - then, yes `O(1)`.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Edited. Good point.

Comment: A skip list could get you close to O(log n), depending on how many layers and size of the skip lanes, but not O(1)

Comment: Genuine question: why? What's the use case for this data structure? Stackoverflow's not for posing challenges, it's for asking help in solving programming problems, so what is the actual programming problem that you have, that you think dictates these constraints on your data structure?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Done.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik if sorted hash map is based on binary tree then its basic operations cost is O(logn) not O(nlogn).

Comment: @epcpu yes. sorry. my mistake. Anyway, it is definetly not O(1) than for HashMap

Comment: @Mooncrater There is no single built-in data structure in Java SDK that would achieve what you're looking for. A quick search for a 3P libaray didn't yield any result. You'll have to implement it yourself, something like this: https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/124998/Design-a-data-structure-that-supports-insert-delete-search-and-getRandom-in-constant-time./123231